# Ceph RBD kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, c, ceph

Within [ceph kernel client](https://github.com/ceph/ceph-client), I am looking for functions responsible for rbd block open/read/write operations.

Since `/drivers/block/rbd.c` contains function `rbd_open()`, it looked as a suitable candidate for narrowing my search. However, I tried to print-debug some of interesting functions in the file without any results, so I presume R/W functionality isn't contained here. Docs aren't very helping and kernel comments are pretty much missing.

Do you know where to look for these functions? Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend to address that issue to the ceph community: https://ceph.io/irc/ There are several mailing lists that you could subscribe to.

Comment: @eblock it's already in IRC channels, I'll try mailing lists later. It is surprising to me how non-documented this code actually is.